# In EMR, Pig Script integrated with HBase failing while trying to load data

Tags: hbase, apache-pig, emr

I am executing a `pig` script which has an interaction with `HBase` and I am getting the below error:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate
>   'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments     at
>   org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:770)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:885)
>     ... 38 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:738)
>     ... 39 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setCacheBlocks(Z)V    at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.initScan(HBaseStorage.java:429)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.(HBaseStorage.java:370)
>     ... 44 more

Pig Version : Pig 0.17.0

HBase Version : HBase 1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a Pig 0.16.0 version JAR in the library. So sometimes, when i run a Pig Script in Oozie it picks that version and it connects with HBase 1.x version, which i believe was the reason for the above failure.

So, i have removed that older JAR file, and now the script which integrates with HBase and runs fine with Pig 0.17 version.